# ODE - how to solve this ODE obtained from a geodesic problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, geodesic

I am stuck at solving this ODE that I obtained by trying to compute geodesics:

$$
\begin{equation}
g(\theta) \frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial g(\theta)}{\partial \theta} \left( \frac{d\theta}{dt} \right)^2 = 0.
\end{equation}
$$

where 
$$g(\theta) = \frac{3(\theta^2+1)}{(\theta-1)^2(\theta+1)^2},$$
$$\frac{\partial g(\theta)}{\partial \theta} = \frac{-6\theta(\theta^2 + 3)}{(\theta-1)^3 (\theta+1)^3}$$

Any help? (It has been several years that I have not been confronted to differential equations... Thank you)

We can assume $\theta(0) = \theta_0$ and $\theta(1) = \theta_1$ as initial conditions.

In SAGEMath, I obtain:

```
-1/2*(sqrt(2)*arcsinh(2*(theta(t) - 1)/abs(2*theta(t) + 2)) + sqrt(2)*arcsinh(2*(theta(t) + 1)/abs(2*theta(t) - 2)) - 2*arcsinh(theta(t)))/_K1 == _K2 + t
```

Comment: Hi. Are you sure you obtained that equation through the geodesic equation? It's just that unless your geometry is one dimensional, the Euler-Lagrange equations for the metric typically give coupled ODEs. You have a single one here, unless some symmetry simplifications were made!

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. It is indeed one dimensional (well, for now, I restrained myself to study the one-dimensional case). So the Christoffel is only $\frac{\partial g(\theta)}{\partial \theta}$ here.

Comment: Okay. That's what I thought. In any case, this ODE is second-order and looks incredibly nonlinear. I think you have to solve it numerically, which can be done in Mathematica with NDSolve or MATLAB. I am not familiar with Sage, although, it seems that the output you have gotten has given you an implicit solution for $\theta(t)$.

Comment: Note also that you don't have initial conditions, you have boundary conditions (at $t=0$ and $t=1$).   But you can use those to obtain the values of the constants _K1 and _K2 in the Sage solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sage gave you the solution (in implicit form).  Maple's is essentially the same:

$$ {\rm arcsinh} \left(\theta\right)-\frac{\sqrt {2}}{2}{\rm arctanh} \left(
\,{\frac {1+\theta}{\sqrt {2\,{\theta}^{2}+2}}}\right)+\frac{\sqrt 
{2}}{2}{\rm arctanh} \left({\frac {1-\theta}{\sqrt {2\,{\theta}^{2}
+2}}}\right)-{c_1}\,t-{c_2}=0
$$

Write this as $f(\theta) = c_1 t + c_2$.  The boundary conditions give you the values of $c_1$ and $c_2$: $c_2 = f(\theta_0)$, $c_1 = f(\theta_1) - f(\theta_0)$.

The graph of $f(\theta)$ looks like this:

[image]

Note the singularities at $\theta = \pm 1$, where $f(\theta) \to \pm \infty$.
On each of the intervals $(-\infty, -1)$, $(-1,1)$ and $(1,+\infty)$ the function is monotone, so there will be a unique solution to your initial value problem if $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$ are both in one of those intervals.  If $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$ are in different intervals, there is no solution.  You might have guessed that from the fact that $g(\theta)$ is singular at $\theta = \pm 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is equivalent to

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \left[\sqrt{g(\theta)} \dot{\theta}\right] = 0 $$

which gives

$$ g(\theta) \dot{\theta} = C $$

this is a separable ODE and can be solved implicitly for $t$ as a function of $\theta$ by partial fractions. If you are lucky the function becomes easily invertible.

Comment: But in this case it is not easily invertible: see the Sage solution.

Answer (score 2):

The calculus below shows how to solve the ODE.

This leads to an integral which can be expressed on a closed form : it is the formula already given by SAGE. So, I didn't rewrite it.

The result is $t$ as a function of $\theta$. I don't think that the inverse function $\theta(t)$ can be expressed on a closed form.

[image]